# How to Align 'Total' Text to the Left in a Right-to-Left ApexCharts Bar Graph?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I created a bar graph using ApexCharts and displayed the total at the end of each column, which looks fine.

However, when I try to switch the chart to a right-to-left orientation using the `yaxis: { reversed: true }` configuration, the 'total' text overlaps with text on the right side. Is there a way to align the 'total' text to the left?

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6qwkyo?file=index.ts)

Before rtl:

[image]

After rtl `yaxis: { reversed: true }`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is a basic example of how to do it.

The important code to adjust the labels are the formatter and the offsetX.

```
 dataLabels: {
  offsetX: -15,
  formatter: function (val) {
   return val + "K"
  }
 }
```

**Basic Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeiryuV/L47n96th/194/